# How to create a form with a text area and two buttons, each with a different action?

Tags: javascript, html, express, pug

I'm using Express.js and Jade and would like to create a form that consists of a textarea and two buttons, each of which invokes a different action. I came up with this but not sure if that's the proper way to do this since pressing the button only redirects but making one button submit does not differentiate it from pressing the other button:

```
form(method='post', action='')
  textarea(wrap="soft" placeholder="Leave a reply...").fixit-reply
  a.btn.btn-primary(href="/resolve") Resolve
  a.btn.btn-warning(href="/comment") Comment
```

Ideally, one action would be caught with `app.post('/resolve', handle);` and the other with `app.post('/comment', handleC);`.

Comment: @nnnnnn How would I test which button was pressed?

Comment: @nnnnnn Right you are :) Thanks! You can post it as an answer if you like and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(As requested, my original comments formed up into an answer.)

Although this can be handled client-side with JS, I'm not familiar with Express.js or Jade so I don't know how to integrate a JS solution with your existing code.

However, if both buttons are submit buttons you can test server-side which one was pressed and redirect as appropriate, thus avoiding the need for any client-side JS. The `name` and `value` of whichever submit button is clicked will be submitted along with other form data. The button that wasn't clicked will not be included in the form data. So you could give both buttons `name="action"` and then server-side you'd test that parameter and redirect according to the associated `value`. (Or give your buttons different `name` attributes and test server-side whether the parameter for a particular button exists at all.) Of course you'd need to give your form an `action="something"` attribute corresponding to the server-side action that does the test and redirect.

In my opinion a server-side only solution is better for this particular requirement because it's easy to do, it keeps the client-side stuff simple, and (obviously) will work even in browsers where the end user has disabled JavaScript (not that many users do that, but it does happen).

Answer (score 0):

Client side, jade template, 2 buttons, fulfill "xss" with different data from different button:

```
  form#formTestHtml1(name="htmlForm",method="post",action="/testhtml")
  button#btnSubmit1(type="submit" name="xss" value="s-html") Submit to sanitize-html
  br
  button#btnSubmit2(type="submit" name="xss" value="bleach") Submit to bleach
```

Server side, check the value of "xss" ( I used node.js and express for routing in the example)

```
router.post('/testhtml', function (req, res, next) {
    var sanitizedStr = "";
    if ( req.body.xss && req.body.xss == "sanitize-html" ) {
        sanitizedStr = "sanitize-html";
    } else
    if ( req.body.xss && req.body.xss == "bleach" ) {
        sanitizedStr = "bleach";
    } else {
        sanitizedStr = "xss undefined or unknown";
    }
    res.render(sanitizedStr);
});
```

It's a real-life example, I took it from a page, when i test snippets for XSS with different html/css sanitizers. Simplified, ofc.